# Creating a basic web page to trigger a Python script

Tags: python, web-applications

I have a Python script that loops through a list of SQL queries read from an Excel file, executes them, and stores output results to a .csv file.

Currently I trigger this from the command line locally.  I would like to create a very basic Web page, something that basically has a button to click to execute the Python script for now. If I can get the output file stored there somehow as well, even better.

The idea being I would start with it locally, but then move the web page somewhere where my team could access it and do the same thing.

I don't need much functionality at all for this web page obviously but this stuff is new to me so not quite sure where to start.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: python3 -m http.server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask) would be a decent choice for a simple web app.

folder structure:

```
├── app.py
├── static
│   ├── index.html
```

app.py (**EDIT** added index.html route handling, duh doy)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', template_folder='static')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return app.send_static('index.html')

@app.route('/execute')
def execute_sql_logic():
    # Do stuff here
    return 'SQL executed', 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You'll need to export FLASK_APP=app.py in your working directory

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href='/execute'><button>execute SQL</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Simplest example I could think of.
Now when you'll run `app.py` and navigate to `localhost:5000` (Port defaults to 5000 if I remember correctly) you'll see the HTML page with the `execute SQL` button. Clicking on it will send a GET to `localhost:5000/execute` which in turn will call your function.
Deploying on a server is beyond the scope of this answer unfortunately.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to explain that to me.  I will look into it!